# Nuxt v2.14 Firebase Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

My Nuxt app is hosted on Firebase. After I updated nuxt dependancy from 2.10.2 to 2.14.1 the live build crushes. The app works great locally, but when I deploy it using `firebase deploy`, I only see generic loading animation. In console there's only one message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in commons.ce964e3.js:1

I did try to delete `node_modules` directory along with `package-lock.json` and install dependancies again - it did not help.

Answer (score 3):

I did have the same issue earlier on. What I did was: creating an app in Nuxt and trying to deploy. The error I had was:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in commons.a599632.js:1
```

**How I fixed it:**

Edit firebase.json by removing `/node_modules/` from the ignore line.

It should read something like:

```
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*"],
```

Comment: Spot on ! Now that nuxt generates a `commons.js` file under `dist/_nuxt/node_modules/`, removing the line ensures the file makes it throught deployment ! Thanks

Comment: Is there any downfall to removing the `node_modules` line?